# CartThrob - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: cartthrob, server, error-500, error-502

I keep getting random "502 Bad Gateway - nginx" errors cropping up on a clients website when using Cart Throb.

For example I tried to install the example templates & chanmels inside Cart Throb, but it through the 502 error, when it got to this URL:

**https://website.co.uk/admin.php?S=3299b90f3382da657f76b0fb2746336bdb26ebd9&D=cp&C=addons_modules&M=show_module_cp&module=cartthrob&method=install_templates**

It also does it *sometimes* when a customer pays for something, using the SagePay gateway.

What could be causing this? I've tried turning off secure forms in the settings and its still doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You may have already resolved this, but in case you haven't or for anyone else running into this issue, I resolved it by adding the following to my nginx.conf file within the http {} tags located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf on your server:

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

Then restart your nginx service via SSH with the following command:

```
'service nginx restart'
```

This worked for me, but for some others the fastcgi_buffer also needed to be updated.  If the above does not work, then you may want to reference this answer:

[Upstream too big - nginx + codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894386/upstream-too-big-nginx-codeigniter)